# How do I take a string and alphabetize it and counter the number of words in it?

Tags: bash

Basically my problem is this, I have a string delimited by periods, I want to be able to print each word on a new line with the number of times it occurs next to it.

Here is what I have already:
EDIT:

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAM=$1 
FILE=${1-test.txt}
#echo $FILE

temp=$( tr '\n' '.' <$FILE )

arr=$(echo $temp | tr "." "\n")

for x in $arr
do
    echo "$x"
done
```

All this does is print out each word on a line. Now I need to count the number of times each word appears and then print it out next to the word. For example:

temp contents = apple, pear, apple, peach

Output should be:

```
apple 2
pear 1
apple 2
peach 1
```

where each word is on a new line.

Comment: And what is your problem with that script? Whats the expected output for some sample input, and whats the actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniq(1)` can probably do what you want. For example:

```
$ echo 'foo.bar.baz.bar.foo.box.foo' | tr '.' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
      2 bar
      1 baz
      1 box
      3 foo
$
```

Note that `uniq` requires sorted input to be able to properly count occurrences.

Comment: I am getting a command not found error when I try to run this

Comment: You don't include dollar sign in the command. @nandhp is just using the dollar sign to symbolise the prompt. Copy everything on the first line AFTER the dollar sign, but not including the dollar sign. (Also, only type the command from the first line. Everything else in the answer is part of the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in awk. given a file that looks like this:

```
this.is.a.test
and.this.is.test2
and.this.is.test3
```

the following awk will give you the words and their counts

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        FS="."
    }
    {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
            a[$i]++
        }
    } 
    END{ 
        for(word in a)print word, a[word]
    }'
```

would produce the following output:

```
test 1
a 1
test2 1
test3 1
and 2
this 3
is 3
```